# Changing account security to create app password through API

Tags: google-oauth

I'd like to at least automate some of this process:
https://forwardemail.net/en/faq#how-to-send-mail-as-using-gmail

It asks for an app password to forward emails under a different email username. Can either the app password generation part or the email username part be automated?

Answer (score 0):

No apps password must be created by the user in their google account after enabling 2fa.

Im not sure about googles TOS though using an apps password in a third party system like this.   It should not be something that is shared in my opinion.

Comment: I don't remember if the password is shared, but can any of the further configurations be automated? You then have to get into deep mailbox settings to allow sending mail under alias.